# add path for pipelinemodel in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-ml

I want to add path for `Pipelinemodel` in spark to load model from my local file system but it returns the following exception.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel
val pipeline =  PipelineModel.load("C:/Users/meh/Desktop/PARC_ACTIF_OM/Partie1_OM/Models_save")

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/meh/Desktop/PARC_ACTIF_OM/Partie1_OM/Models_save/model_final.sav/metadata
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:251)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

Comment: I'm going to guess the files does exist.  Could you add output to show the permissions on : C:/Users/meh/Desktop/PARC_ACTIF_OM/Partie1_OM/Models_save/model_final.sav/metadata

Comment: metadata does not exist just when executing it appears but i changed work in hdfs but i find same error

Comment: scala> val pipeline =  PipelineModel.load("hdfs:/myhdfs/user/mba/model_final.sav")
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs:/myhdfs/user/mba/model_final.sav/metadata

Answer (score 0):

If C:/Users/meh/Desktop/PARC_ACTIF_OM/Partie1_OM/Models_save/model_final.sav/metadata does not exist then you likely have a format issue.  The format you are saving the model in is not the format load is looking for the data. (It clearly is calling out that that metadata folder is missing and that seems critical to the load.)

Comment: i think piplinemodel is searching metadata of file to use it for load what do u think ?